# VBA msgBox - vbYes keeps calling wrong sub

Tags: ms-access, vba, call, msgbox

If I click on yes, VBA keeps going to the function Mandate? What did I do wrong?

```
Public AutoDate As Date
Public NewDate As String

Public Sub GetDate()  ' DATUM BEPALEN
    AutoDate = Date - 1
    MsgBox (AutoDate), (vbYesNo), ("Datum")
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
        If Response = vbYes Then
            NewDate = AutoDate
            Call DeleteDate
        Else    ' No
            Call ManDate
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the result of MsgBox to Response.
Not sure if VbMsgBoxResult is a valid data type in that instance either.

Try either of these:

```
Public Sub GetDate()  ' DATUM BEPALEN

    AutoDate = Date - 1

    If MsgBox(AutoDate, vbYesNo, "Data") = vbYes Then
        NewDate = AutoDate
        Call DeleteDate
    Else    ' No
        Call ManDate
    End If

End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub GetDate()  ' DATUM BEPALEN

        Dim Response As Long

        AutoDate = Date - 1
        Response = MsgBox(AutoDate, vbYesNo, "Data")

        If Response = vbYes Then
            NewDate = AutoDate
            Call DeleteDate
        Else    ' No
            Call ManDate
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: After a quick check you could set Response as a VbMsgBoxResult type in the second example `Dim Response = VbMsgBoxResult`  It will return 6 for Yes, 7 for No.

Answer (score 1):

You need retrieve the Response as the return of the MsgBox function:

```
Dim Response as Integer
Response= MsgBox( AutoDate, vbYesNo, "Datum")
```

Now you can if-test Response to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable to capture the response ...

```
Dim ans As Integer
ans = MsgBox("hello", vbYesNo, "Datum")
If ans = vbYes Then
   MsgBox "Yes"
Else
   MsgBox "No"
End If
```